# Trick to factor: $n^3 + 6n^2 + 9n + 4$

Tags: polynomials

Is there any way to tell if

$$n^3 + 6n^2 + 9n + 4$$

has a factored (condensed) form, and, if so, what that factored form is? If the answer is yes to both, may one explain the more general principle?

Comment: Hint:  search for rational roots.

Comment: You can't simplyfie it, you can factor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, for $f(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn^1+dn^0$, we have
$$f(-1)=a-b+c-d=(a+c)-(b+d)$$

In other words, if the sum of the even co-efficients is equal to the sum of the odd co-efficients, $(x+1)$ can be taken out. Here, this holds

Then we have:

$$(n+1)(pn^2+qn+r)=n^3+6n^2+9n+4$$
Expanding out the LHS, we get:
$$pn^3+(p+q)n^2+(q+r)n+r=n^3+6n^2+9n+4$$
Can you see that $p=1, q=5, r=4$ by matching terms?

So we have:

$$n^3+6n^2+9n+4=(n+1)(n^2+5n+4)$$

Factorise the second bracket and you're done.

Comment: Long division is more efficient than indeterminate coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Let's factor it!

$$\begin{align*}n^3+6n^2+9n+4 & =n^3+6n^2+8n+n+4\\ & =n(n^2+6n+8)+n+4\\ & =n(n+4)(n+2)+n+4\\ & =(n+4)(n^2+2n+1)\\ & =(n+1)^2(n+4)\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ 1+9 = 10  $$
$$ 6+4 = 10 $$
Either $1$ or $-1$ is a root. I'm betting on $-1$

Comment: Further $\, 2(1+4)=10\ $ so $\, {-}1\,$ is at least a *double* root, so clearly $\, f(n) = (n\!+\!1)^2(n\!+\!4)\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$$ n^3+6n^2+9n+4 = (n^3+1)+(6n^2+6n)+(3n+3)$$
$$ = (n+1)(n^2-n+1)+6n(n+1)+3(n+1)=$$

$$ = (n+1)(n^2-n+1+6n+3)$$
$$ = (n+1)(n^2+5n+4) =$$ $$= (n+1)^2(n+4)$$

Answer (score 0):

The general "principle" is called [Polynomial factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials). We have
$$
n^3+6n^2+9n+4=(n+1)^2(n+4).
$$
There are many interesting algorithms. In this particular example, it is enough to do the [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). It immediately gives that a rational root must be of the form $\pm 1,\pm 4$, and then you just try. For a more demanding example, then, try to factorize
$$
 n^9 + 3n^7 + 3n^6 + 3n^5 + 6n^4 + 4n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1.
$$
The result is very short and nice.

Comment: Thanks, Dietrich! :)

Comment: Surely you mean [polynomial factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials)???

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, was a typo, thank you. Corrected now!

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, $1+9=6+4$ so that $-1$ is a root. Now by long division,

$$\frac{n^3+6n^2+9n+4}{n+1}=n^2+5n+4$$ and you can use the quadratic formula.

Or by inspection, $-1$ is again a root and

$$\frac{n^2+5n+1}{n+1}=n+4.$$